# Changing JRadioButton Icon on Windows 7

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I created a method which changes the icon of all jradiobuttons from a buttongroup:

```
public void setRadioButtonIcons(final ButtonGroup gruppe){

        Enumeration<AbstractButton> gruppeEnum = gruppe.getElements();

    while (gruppeEnum.hasMoreElements()){
        AbstractButton radio = gruppeEnum.nextElement(); 
        Icon unselIcon = new ImageIcon( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox0.jpg").getPath()); 
        Icon selIcon = new ImageIcon( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox1.jpg").getPath());
        radio.setIcon(unselIcon); 
        radio.setSelectedIcon(selIcon);
    }

    }
```

This works fine under Ubuntu with Java 1.6.0_16.

When I use the methode under windows 7 with java 1.6.0_18, the icons do not apear. They are simply missing. The programm does not throw a Nullpointer... it finds the icons, but does not display them. Any ideas? It seems somewhat hard to believe that I can not use such a simple functionality under windows.

I tried it with gif and jpg. I also put the images inside the jar and tried to load them from the filesystem -> same result.

Edit: In this configuration, the files are loaded from the jar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Icon unselIcon = new ImageIcon( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox0.jpg").getPath()); 
    Icon selIcon = new ImageIcon( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox1.jpg").getPath());
```

You shouldn't be calling getPath() there, should just be:

```
    Icon unselIcon = new ImageIcon( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox0.jpg")); 
    Icon selIcon = new ImageIcon( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox1.jpg"));
```

It won't be able to access a resource in a jar by path and an ImageIcon can load an image using a URL just fine.

If you still are not seeing your icons then it may be that the L&F you are using does not use those icons and instead uses its own. Perhaps try testing the code with a different L&F.

Comment: I have to mod-up your answer, since you came to the same conclusion as I did but did it faster. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the calls to `getPath()`, like this:

```
public void setRadioButtonIcons(final ButtonGroup gruppe) {
    Enumeration<AbstractButton> gruppeEnum = gruppe.getElements();
    while (gruppeEnum.hasMoreElements()){
        AbstractButton radio = gruppeEnum.nextElement(); 
        Icon unselIcon = new ImageIcon(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox0.jpg")); 
        Icon selIcon = new ImageIcon(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("checkbox1.jpg"));
        radio.setIcon(unselIcon); 
        radio.setSelectedIcon(selIcon);
    }
}
```

The problem is that `URL.getPath()` gives you a string URL, which isn't necessarily a valid string filename of the sort that the `ImageIcon` string constructor expects.  Fortunately, `ImageIcon` has another constructor that understands `URL` objects, and so there's no need to call `getPath()`.

Comment: And now I see that somebody else figured this out too as I was working on it... That'll teach me to post answers before I'm 100% sure that they're correct and complete, won't it? ;-)